# iOS Automation Appium: How to lock screen for iPhone real device without a duration?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ui-automation, appium-ios

I want to automate the following case: locking my screen of the real device and open the screen again from an APNS - like answer a call from APNS.
Therefore I would like to just lock the screen without a certain amount of time, so that I can unlock it by swiping on the push notification.
I know there is in AppiumDriver the ***lockScreen(int seconds)*** but I just want to implement ***lockScreen()*** method.
Any of you have an idea how to do that? How I could solve that with Apple script or with Appium Driver?
thanks a lot
Jules

Answer (score 0):

This is the desired behavior. The locking-waiting-unlocking is necessary for iOS, where it is the only way to do any locking. 
For Android it should just lock. If you want it to unlock, you can call unlock.