# Is there a way to lock iPhone screen, then I can do testing on the lock screen and then unlock it again?

Tags: ios, appium, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I have a test where I want to lock my iPhone device for some time until I finish testing on the phone lock screen and then unlock it again. I referred to this article on stack overflow [iOS Automation Appium: How to lock screen for iPhone real device without a duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568028/ios-automation-appium-how-to-lock-screen-for-iphone-real-device-without-a-durat) which talks about lockScreen(int seconds).

I cannot use this as this method will take care of locking and unlocking the device for that duration. Also the driver gets blocked on it until the unlock of the phone completes. How can I slide in my tests in between lock and unlock?

Comment: what kind of tests do you want to do while screen is locked?

Comment: I want to lock my phone then check for the notification to be present in the notification center and then unlock it back. I have the logic to read the notification its just I cannot control the lock and unlock.